# My code doesn't run properly, what is wrong in there?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

```
hand = ['A','Q']
points = 0
player_cards1 = ['2']
value1 = 2
player_cards2 = ['3']
value2 = 3
player_cards3 = ['4']
value3 = 4
player_cards4 = ['5']
value4 = 5
player_cards5 = ['6']
value5 = 6
player_cards6 = ['7']
value6 = 7
player_cards7 = ['8']
value7 = 8
player_cards8 = ['9']
value8 = 9
player_cards9 = ['T']
value9 = 10
player_cards10 = ['Q']
value10 = 10
player_cards11 = ['K']
value11 = 10
player_cards12 = ['J']
value12 = 10
ACE11 = ['A']
value13 = 11

for hand in player_cards1:
    flag = True
    if flag == True:
        points = points + value1
    for hand in ACE11:
        flag = True
        if flag == True:
            points = points + value13
        for hand in player_cards2:
            flag = True
            if flag == True:
                points = points + value2
            for hand in player_cards3:
                flag = True
                if flag == True:
                    points = points + value3
                for hand in player_cards4:
                    flag = True
                    if flag == True:
                        points = points + value4
                    for hand in player_cards5:
                        flag = True
                        if flag == True:
                            points = points + value5
                        for hand in player_cards6:
                            flag = True
                            if flag == True:
                                points = points + value6
                            for hand in player_cards7:
                                flag = True
                                if flag == True:
                                    points = points + value7
                                for hand in player_cards8:
                                    flag = True
                                    if flag == True:
                                        points = points + value8
                                    for hand in player_cards9:
                                        flag = True
                                        if flag == True:
                                            points = points + value9
                                        for hand in player_cards10:
                                            flag = True
                                            if flag == True:
                                                points = points + value10
                                            for hand in player_cards11:
                                                flag = True
                                                if flag == True:
                                                    points = points + value11
                                                for hand in player_cards12:
                                                    flag = True
                                                    if flag == True:
                                                        points = points + value12
                                                    print points
```

It ran fine in the first five blocks and then it just gives me to total value of the whole deck (95). How do I fix this? It's supposed to give me the value of the cards in the Hand only. What did I do wrong in here?

Comment: OMG, you really need to refactor your code

Comment: It's properly formatted. It's just... uniquely written.

Comment: yes I'm pretty sure you guys find it amusing (not offended), I honestly didn't know how else to make it work because I tried other ways and it didn't work out so well for me. I know it should return a proper value but it doesn't

Comment: Really, I didn't found it amusing at all and I wasn't joking. I have a rule of thumb: whenever I found myself writing nested loops, if a reach the third it may be time for some refactoring. Perhaps you could explain the whole idea of what exactly are you trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

Your line:

```
for hand in player_cards1:
```

Probably is not doing what you expect it to do.  It looks like you think it's going to compare hand and player_cards1; instead what it does is create an iterator on player_cards1 that you access via the variable hand (meaning that hand is getting re-assigned, and will no longer be ['A', 'Q']).  Here's a simpler example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
for item in a: //creates an iterator around a, with the variable item to refer to each list member
  print item
```

That three line program would output:

```
1
2
3
```

Instead, you probably want to iterate over the cards in the hand, e.g.:

```
for card in hand:
  //code here to look up the value of the card and add it to a running total
```

I'd also suggest rethinking the way you're tracking card values, as it's going to be very cumbersome . . . hint: there's only a few special cases where you can't use the card's face value.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited to make the answer more didactical.**

Use a [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) to store the scores for each card.

```
card_points = { 'A': 11, '2': 2, ... }
```

Then you can iterate over each `card` in `hard`, look up its value in the dictionary, and sum the scores to give the total.

You might want to look at the [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) function which could be useful here.

Comment: ... you did something, that is completely not didactical, as it seemed like a homework for me and the poster should have been instructed on how to do it for him/herself rather then have it solved...

Comment: @MarkByers well, not from me. I wasn't joking at all

Comment: Well I'm sorry I'm no computer genius like some of you people I'm a Biochemistry major and this course is mandatory. You don't have to write out an answer for me just a suggestion on how to do it is good.

Comment: @Miroslav Hudak: I'm really bored, so I'm going to weight in because... well, because I can. Mark Byers' answer looks pretty didactic to me... There's not an specific implementation, just pointing what to do... The question's poster still has a lot of work to do there (hey, IMHO). Besides, this site is to ask/answer things, not necessarily to *teach* programming. I believe it's the course's professor's task to check whether his/her students actually **know** programming (dunno... by making questions about the assignment maybe)... Man, I'm bored!!

Comment: @Borrajax - you should check what his answer was before it was edited, which is when that non-didactic comment was made . . .

Comment: @Eliza - check out my answer which explains why your code is not behaving the the way you expect, and a nudge in the right direction

Comment: @ernie... Fraggin' *edit* feature!! **:-D** Thanks for clarifying. I was actually very surprised of people considering the current answer not didactic!

Comment: @BorrajaX you see, and I'm a programmer... and was a teacher... and I've seen so many crappy programmers, who got the job just because nobody cares these days about the quality of code and then, you have to work with code like that, because it was written and it was paid for... i have my own business now, trying to do my best... but then, there are people, willing to work for little money selling crappy code which is - working at best. and they win the bid... you know what i'm telling? when people have a degree / class / course in programming, they should know how to do it (no offence Eliza).

Comment: I understand what you are saying but there is nothing I can do about being horrific in programming. I'm never going to be good at it no matter what. You are saying that if people have a course they should know how to but that's not how it works. I have to take one computer class. I'm a 3rd year student and I have a good GPA it's unfair how my grade is going to go down because of one class I won't have any need in my future career. The computer programs I use for my labs aren't that complicated as we are instructed before hand. I still have no idea what python has to do with my degree.

Comment: @Miroslav Hudak... That is true... But Eliza also has a point in the answer... and now I'm trying to... erm... to... to make everybody happy, and I'm gonna shut up before I get banned from this site **:-D** Still bored, but I'm gonna go watch a movie online (I'm not sure if I can say Netflix in this page... Can I?... No, probably not) Miroslav, I totally understand what you're saying (I have a whole project to prove you right), but then I get into flower-power mode and I go blame the *system* and wonder how the people who created that can pass enough credit hours to get a Master in C.S.

Comment: @BorrajaX: Sorry for confusing you with the edit. I was hoping that Miroslav would be kind and delete his comment after I fixed my answer, but since he didn't I've decided on a different approach. I've put a huge notice at the start of my answer which should hopefully help people to see that the comments have been addressed and the answer is vastly improved from when the comment was originally made.